# Best mobile theme for iOS devices?

Tags: theming

Can anyone please tell me the best mobile theme I could use for iOS devices? I tried the iUI theme but it doesn't display the table with the info properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Mobile](http://drupal.org/project/jquerymobile) or [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) themes

Comment: Thanks, but these don't exactly fit naturally. I was looking something more like iUI - that actually takes table info and puts it into an iOS look; making it not look like a website. The only problem I have with iUI is that it doesn't display the NavigationViewControllerBar as it should.

Comment: jQuery Mobile does exactly that. http://drupal.org/project/jquerymobile - We've used it along with ThemeKey to display this theme on mobile devices for a natural iOS look. There is even a jQm skin for iOS. http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/7240874402/ios-inspired-jquery-mobile-theme-jquery-mobile